# Posicionar imagem relativa a outra mesmo mudando resolução

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o logotipo e um triângulo preto de fundo. Como posicionar o logo para sempre ficar no centro do triângulo mesmo mudando a resolução?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<img class="img-responsive triangulo-laranja" src="{{ asset('storage/triangulo.fw.png') }}">
<div class="img-responsive triangulo-logo">
    <img class="img-responsive logo" src="{{ asset('storage/logo.png') }}">
</div>

.triangulo-laranja {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 997;
width: 85%;
height: 90%;
opacity: 0.85;
}

.triangulo-logo {
background-image: url('../../storage/triangulo-logo.fw.png');
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 8%;
z-index: 998;
width: 600px;
height: 200px;
}

.logo {
position: relative; 
top: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -95px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Possivelmente tu já deve ter pensado isso, mas em todo caso...Não seria mais interessante juntar o logo à imagem?

Comment: Sim, eu até fiz isso, mas por questões do design estou tentando fazer o posicionamento com imagens separadas.

Comment: Entendi, imaginei isso, Marcelo por acaso tu não conseguiria criar um snippet(Ctrl+M na edição da pergunta), só com a parte que nos interessa, mostrando o problema acontecendo de fato, ficaria melhor p/ te ajudar.

Comment: Na primeira esta correto, o logo esta centralizado no triangulo. Ao mudar a orientacao (no caso iphone 6 o logo nao fica centralizado no triangulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, o problema está ocorrendo pelo fato de você estar usando position: absolute em ambos os elementos. Pela sua explicação a uma resposta anterior esse triangulo preto também é uma imagem assim como a logo.

Uma possível solução seria você criar uma div englobando a logo e colocar o triangulo preto como uma imagem de background nessa div que está englobando a sua logo. Por exemplo:

```
/*---- Código HTML ----*/

<div class="divlogo">
    <img class="logoimg" src="./img/logo.png" />
</div>

/*---- Código CSS ----*/

.divlogo{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 998;
   width: 80%; 
   height: 30%;
   text-align: center;
   background-image: url("./img/tringulo-preto.png");
   background-size: 100%; /*Caso 100% não lhe agrade pode usar Cover*/
}

.logoimg{
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

**Observação**: Ajustes os valores de tamanho dos elementos de acordo com a sua necessidade. Espero que essa resposta lhe ajude.

Comment: Sua solução está quase 100%. O logo esta ficando centralizado dentro do triângulo independente de mudar a resolução. Estou utilizando o bootstrap só que agora não consigo mais colocar a classe img-responsive no triangulo e tive que definir width e height pra ele, com isso ele não se adapta quando abro no mobile. Coloquei o código atual na pergunta.

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque você utilizou tamanho em pixels na classe .trigangulo-logo utilize porcentagem assim ele vai sempre se adaptar, caso não fique do seu agrado pode estar fazendo um media screen para ajustar a resolução desejada.